# Valgrind misses an Uninitialised Value Warning

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

There is a variable 'flag' being used to indicate whether a particular scenario is true or false:

> ```
> char             flag;
> ```

This variable is part of a class, and is **not initialized** to any value.

It is subsequently used in a code segment like this:

```
if(a)
{
------
}
else if(flag)
{
-----
}
else if(b)
{
------
}
```

When Valgrind is run with MemCheck, there is no **Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)** warning thrown by Valgrind, even though the **else if(flag)** code segment is hit.

The variable 'b' is also uninitialized, but Valgrind correctly throws a warning for it.

Is there any possible explanation as to why Valgrind would miss the warning for **'flag'** variable? Is it due to some sort of compiler optimization?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: are you sure `char flag;` is `auto`?

Comment: Without seeing some proper code (like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it's impossible to say anything. Chances are that the variable *is* initialized somewhere, and you just missed it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg To make sure that it is indeed uninintialised, i used the same 'flag' variable in a simple if() condition a few lines before the above mentioned code segment. In this case, Valgrind indeed threw up a warning. So my question is why isnt the error shown in the above mentioned code?

Comment: The need for a minimal, complete and verifiable example remains...

Comment: Which optimization level do you use?

Comment: is `a` always true, so the compiler eliminates the rest